# connect to alfresco 2017 using alfresco-web-service-client

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-maven

I am using `alfresco-web-service-client 5.0.a`, I am trying to login into  alfresco-community 2017 which is deployed at : `localhost:8081/alfresco`.

This is what I've done so far :

```
    import org.alfresco.webservice.authentication.AuthenticationFault;
    import org.alfresco.webservice.util.AuthenticationUtils;
    import org.alfresco.webservice.util.WebServiceFactory;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws AuthenticationFault  {

            WebServiceFactory.setEndpointAddress("http://localhost:8081/alfresco/api");     
            AuthenticationUtils.startSession("admin", "admin");

        }
    }
```

This is what I get when I run the class :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.alfresco.webservice.util.WebServiceException: Error starting session.
    at org.alfresco.webservice.util.AuthenticationUtils.startSession(AuthenticationUtils.java:99)
    at com.lydec.Main.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:154)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at org.alfresco.webservice.authentication.AuthenticationServiceSoapBindingStub.startSession(AuthenticationServiceSoapBindingStub.java:187)
    at org.alfresco.webservice.util.AuthenticationUtils.startSession(AuthenticationUtils.java:84)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.components.net.DefaultSocketFactory.create(DefaultSocketFactory.java:153)
    at org.apache.axis.components.net.DefaultSocketFactory.create(DefaultSocketFactory.java:120)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
    ... 12 more
```

pom.xml

Comment: Why on earth are you using the ancient deprecated WS* stuff? Why not use the Public Rest API and/or CMIS?

Comment: Yes, Gagravarr is right. You should use CMIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the old (and unstable) 5.0.a web service client to talk to a modern version of Alfresco on the server.

This [link](https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-4707-alfresco-content-management-web-services) provides information on the changes related to SOAP-based web services.

If you must use SOAP-based web services, use CMIS ([sample code](https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/samples/create-session/index.html)).

I would strongly recommend that you instead use REST instead of SOAP-based web services for just about anything. For Alfresco, you can use the new [public REST API](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/pra/1/topics/pra-welcome.html) or you can use CMIS (either the Atom Pub binding or the Browser binding).